# executing a multi-“match-phrase” query in Elastic Search with `or` opeator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, match-phrase

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "or": [
         {"match_phrase": {"text":  "first phrase"}},
         {"match_phrase": {"text":  "second phrase"}}
      ]
    }
 }
}
```

**I want to match all documents that contain one of phrases exactly as entered.**

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                 "bool" : {
                    "or" : [
                        { "term" : { "text" : "first phrase" } }, 
                        { "term" : { "text" : "second phrase" } } 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```